# Are CRAN checks publicly logged?

Tags: r, cran

When we run something along the lines of `R CMD check mypackage_1.2.0.tar.gz --as-cran` are there public logs available? (e.g. through an API perhaps)

I am interested to know because it could be useful info for package maintainers to know. Note: I am aware a package maintainer could set up Ci tools themselves, but it could still be of interest to know the status of checks.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you under the impression that that option literally has CRAN run the checks remotely? That isn't the case. The output will be available locally just like when you don't use the as-cran option.

Comment: @Dason no I know most of the checks occur locally, but some (maintainer, version) require contact with CRAN. So I wasn’t sure if cran publicly logs these checks (and/or some others)

Comment: They are. But just running the checks locally and using -as-cran doesn't require any contact with CRAN. They run those checks when a package is actually submitted. Maybe that's what you meant to refer to but isn't what you said.